# How to access a form field's custom attribute at save time in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Should be awarding double points for this one; I think it's going to be tricky.

Say for example I had a form field which looked like this:

```
<li><label for="id_question_3_1"><input name="question_3" question_id="3" type="radio" class="inlinechoice" value="4" id="id_question_3_1" /> Agree</label></li>
```

And I really really had to put that custom attribute `"question_id"` into my response that I was saving into the database.  How would I go about grabbing it?  I can't find an example of anyone needing to do this, so can't crib from anyone!

If it's not possible, how do I go about doing it?

I'm building a dynamic form, from some (usually 5 but not necessarily) questions stored in the database.  I need to store the answers along with a reference to the question it refers to.

I've got a response model to store, with a fk to the question, but need to get that custom attr out of the form data that is submitted.

Comment: How are you generating that field (with the custom id) in the first place?

Comment: copy and paste this into a textfile...

    extra_fields = Question.objects.filter(survey=this_survey)
    
    for i, question in enumerate(extra_fields):
        fields['question_%s' % question.id] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'inlinechoice', 'question_id': question.id}, choices=RADIO_CHOICES), label=question)

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of that question_id attribute? Obviously that attribute itself isn't going to come back in the request, unless...

- Parse the name=question_{id} of the input field (if this is the id) which implies you don't really need the question_id attribute
- Server-side, generate a hidden form field with name=question_id and value=3 using your template.
- Client-side, generate a hidden form field with some javascript. Not sure I like this one though, since it relies on the client having javascript.

Hidden form fields are normally the way to go here.

Comment: i thought about hidden form fields.

Comment: question_id contains the id of the question in the database.
when i draw the summary of the survey, i want to be able to say
- the average score for that question across all surveys was...
- the average score for that survey including all questions was...
which means i'll need to know which survey and which question a response belongs to. 

i thought about hidden form fields. to do it with hidden form fields is doable, but i thought it'd be possible to get out of sync if the order got messed up at all?

Comment: so the form would look like

    form
    hidden for question_1
    question_1
    hidden for question_7
    question_7
    hidden for question_11
    question_11

and then at save time you iterate through the form, but how do you know you are getting the attrributes you want in the right order?

i wonder if there is a way of getting the question ids from the Question manager and then asking it to find the cleaned_data where the question_id is equal to each returned by the manager. which would be quite a safe way of making sure none are missed.

Comment: forgive me for missing the obvious, how do i parse the name attr of the input field? this is probably the super simple solution i'm missing.

Comment: The response you get when a form is POSTed is a bunch of name=value pairs. In your view code that handles the response, just get the form fields that match name=question_X and use some python code to split it to get the X...